# Can not set custom title on some WordPress setups

Tags: hooks, title, wp-title

I'm having a bit of an issue changing the title on a custom page. Most the time the standard code works, but for whatever reason on certain WordPress setups I am unable to change the default title.

What usually works, but is not working in this situation:

```
function customtitle(){
    return "custom title";
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'customtitle', 10);
```

I'm also aware of the issues with changing custom titles and the yoast plugin. On the current WordPress setup I'm working with yoast is not installed. I wanted to know if there was another hook or method that I can override the title over the current default title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to difference in your theme's support. Some themes render the title by using the `wp_title` filter, some by using `pre_get_document_title`. If your theme has this line in its `functions.php` file:

```
add_theme_support('title-tag');
```

Then you need to use the `pre_get_document_title` filter, as follows:

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'my_title');
function my_title() {
    return 'Some title';
}
```

This is for the newer versions of WordPress. The old installations might be still using the legacy `wp_title()` function, which you already mentioned in your question.